# when I use perl to load infile into a mysql db,why the count returned is not correct?

Tags: mysql, perl

First,Greetings from Beijing before the  Spring Festival --"过年好!".

I have a perl script to load data file into the database.The script runs good,but the returned information is always not correct.

**Problem**:

the code is like this :

```
     $sql_load="LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE $FileName REPLACE INTO TABLE ".$TableName ;
     $sth=$dbi->do($sql_load) ;#or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
     if(DBI->err){
         print "      after connect, SQL Error:$DBI::errstr\n";
     }else{
         print "      $sth . Records Uploaded \n";
     }
```

the output is like this:

```
     7 . Records Uploaded.
```

**But Actually**:

the wc -l $FileName is 6 (including the first line which is the field names line),
the count of  data line is 5.

the returned count number is always equal the correct number plus 2.

**Question:**
I have googled for this question many times but with no luck,and didn't get useful info from the mysql docs too.
How can I get the right count number?What does   the plus 2 number mean?

Answer (score 0):

This is what [the manual says](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//load-data.html):

> If you specify REPLACE, input rows replace existing rows. In other
>   words, rows that have the same value for a primary key or unique index
>   as an existing row. See [Section 13.2.8, “REPLACE Syntax”](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replace.html).

The `REPLACE` command is known for affecting 2 rows when there is a match because you get a deletion plus an insertion:

> The REPLACE statement returns a count to indicate the number of rows
>   affected. This is the sum of the rows deleted and inserted. If the
>   count is 1 for a single-row REPLACE, a row was inserted and no rows
>   were deleted. If the count is greater than 1, one or more old rows
>   were deleted before the new row was inserted. It is possible for a
>   single row to replace more than one old row if the table contains
>   multiple unique indexes and the new row duplicates values for
>   different old rows in different unique indexes.

So I suspect that you have 5 rows in your file and 2 of them already exist in the database.

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's weird,my script runs once every minute.Every minute there are 5 new records insert into database A. Then I export the data to a file,and load them into database B. So I think the loading process should  not have  the deleting operation.